# variable name subsitutions when put into input

Tags: c, arrays

```
int var_lib_check(char *type, char *var)
{
    static char var_library[MAX_VARS][MAX_LINE];
    static char new_var[MAX_LINE];
    static int num_of_var;
    int z;

    if (strcmp(type, DOUBLE_TYPE) == 0 || strcmp(type, INT_TYPE) == 0 ||
            strcmp(type, RTRN_TYPE)==0)
    {
        for (z = 0 ; z < num_of_var ; z++)
        {
            if (strcmp(var_library[z], var) == 0)
            {
                sprintf(new_var, "x%d", z);
                printf("%s %s\n", type, new_var);
                return z;
            }
        }
        strcpy(var_library[num_of_var], var);
        sprintf(new_var, "x%d", num_of_var);
        printf("%s %s\n", type, new_var);
        num_of_var += 1;
    }
    return num_of_var;
}
```

How would I modify my `var_lib_check()` to apply variable name substitutions to another class statement: Assignment statements from expressions that are individual variables, sums, products, divisions, subtractions of two variables?

for e.g.:

```
double malcolm; would be double x0;.  
int zoe; would be int x1;.  
zoe=wash; would be x1=x2;.  
malcolm=wash*river; would be x0=x2*x3;.
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific. It's hard to understand what you mean. Please show your input, the output you are getting or the expected output, or post narrow down your code to a specific part where you are getting the problem.

Comment: @ArunA.S the input for example would be double malcolm and then it would print double x0. Then next if I enter int zoe, it would print zoe x1. Then next if i print zoe = malcolm it would print x1=x0. How would i modify my code to produce this output?

Comment: I guess you want to build something like an obfuscator, that replaces descriptive variable names with generic ones. This is of course possible, but a useful answer would be by far too large for stackoverflow. The obfuscator must read and parse the source code, identify which tokens are variables, know the scope of those variables, and keep a dictionary that maps between original name and replacement.